# How to bulid a application with QML on MAC OS?

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, qml

I try to build a application with QML on MAC OS. I get errors when start build.

```
Could not parse otool output: "/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/build-rproxychecker2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bit-Debug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/Models.2/libmodelsplugin.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libmodelsplugin.dylib:\n"
Could not parse otool output: "/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/build-rproxychecker2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bit-Debug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/StateMachine/libqtqmlstatemachine.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libqtqmlstatemachine.dylib:\n"
Could not parse otool output: "/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/build-rproxychecker2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bit-Debug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/StateMachine/libqtqmlstatemachine.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libqtqmlremoteobjects.dylib:\n"
Could not parse otool output: "/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/build-rproxychecker2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bit-Debug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/StateMachine/libqtqmlstatemachine.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libqmlplugin.dylib:\n"
...
        "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: string table not at the end of the file (can't be processed) in file:/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/buildrproxychecker2Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bitDebug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/Models.2/libmodelsplugin.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libmodelsplugin.dylib\n" 
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: string table not at the end of the file (can't be processed) in file:/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/buildrproxychecker2Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bitDebug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/Models.2/libmodelsplugin.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libqtqmlstatemachine.dylib\n" 
...
```

I use QT 5.15.2, Xcode 10.3, QtCreator 5.0 and have a file .pro with such parameters.

```
QT += core gui network sql quickwidgets quick quickcontrols2 
...
lupdate_only {
    SOURCES += qml
}
...
macdeployqt $${DESTDIR}/$${TARGET}.app -qmldir=$${PWD}/qml -always-overwrite;
```

I tried to call macdeployqt without -always-overwrite https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57265 , but it did not help. Someone had same problem?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this problem. You have to delete all files with errors like this

```
rm -rf "/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/build-rproxychecker2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bit-Debug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/Models.2/libmodelsplugin.dylib.dSYM" 
rm -rf "/Users/test/qt/dev/projects/TestProject/build-rproxychecker2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_clang_64bit-Debug/debug/ch2.app/Contents/Resources/qml/QtQml/Models.2/libmodelsplugin_debug.dylib.dSYM"
```

Better to make this in a .pro file.